# Is registering listener for light sensor spins the CPU?

Tags: android

I'm newbie to android, I want to know if registering listener for light sensor spins the CPU , because it seems that android by default gets light values and stores it in a file (`/sys/devices/virtual/lightsensor/switch_cmd/lightsensor_file_state` (in some devices)).

Any response will be appreciated.

Comment: No, CPU will stay in place. You need to install a carousel listener to get it to spin. Or: What are you asking?

Answer (score 1):

The "files" exposed via the `sysfs` filesystem (`/sys/*`) are connections to backing Linux kernel data objects.  These are exposed by drivers.  Any of the sensors are accessed via the `SensorManager`.  Registering a listener doesn't "spin" the CPU.  The drivers provide data to to the framework at certain intervals and the framework calls back your listener appropriately.